# How to append blob storage data to multipart/form-data in swift

Tags: swift, multipartform-data

What I need is to create multipart/form-data and implement blob storage for storing JSON data in it.
I JavaScript the code is as below:

media - Is an audio file

```
const body = new FormData()
const data = new Blob(
    [
      JSON.stringify({
        key: "value",
        key1: "value1"
      })
    ],
    {
      type: 'application/json'
    }
  )

  body.append('media', file)
  body.set('data', data)
```

Comment: How does the Swift code looks so far? What have you tried, and where you got stuck?

Comment: Where do 'FormData,' 'Blog,' 'JSON' come from?  Where are you writing code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using [this](https://github.com/davbeck/MultipartForm) library

```
let form = MultipartForm(parts: [
            MultipartForm.Part(name: "data", data: data, contentType: "application/json"),
            MultipartForm.Part(name: "media", data: fileData, filename: audio.lastPathComponent, contentType: "audio/wav"),
        ])
```